# UIImage equality issues – how to compare UIImage to store image data?

Tags: uiimage, nsdata, equality

Both of the following return `NO` for me:

```
[image isEqual:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)]];
[image isEqual:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)]];
```

Is there a proper way to convert NSData back to a UIImage so that I can use the resulting image for equality purposes? And what would be the proper way to test for equality in this case?

My two ideal goals are:

- Given a UIImage, convert to NSData.
- Given another UIImage, check if that UIImage matches the original UIImage currently stored as NSData without having to convert the new UIImage into NSData.

Or is it fully impossible to create a UIImage object using NSData that will match the UIImage object used to create that NSData?

Currently I've gone ahead and updated my code to compare NSData rather than UIImages.